# Bluetooth Low Energy RSSI Calculation

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, distance, positioning, rssi, indoor-positioning-system

I wanted to calculate the RSSI of the received signal. I am working on a program to find the distance between two nodes using BLE RSSI in LabVIEW.
RSSI = -10nlog(d/d0)+A
where d is unknown distance
d0 is reference distance (1 meter)
A is RSSI calculated at 1 meter.
n is path attenuation factor.

I want to know the formula to calculate RSSI. I came across this formula :
RSSI = Txpower (dBm) - PathLoss of the receiving signal(dBm).

I calculated path loss PL(d) at reference distance 1 meter. then I calculated RSSI from this equation.my transmit power was 0dBm and the path loss is 4 dBm. so RSSI is -4 dBM.

Is this method to calculate RSSI is correct? I wanted to calculate RSSI, rather than reading RSSI value from packet. Can anybody help me to how to calculate RSSI of received signal.